# Empty allure report - Allure Report unknown NaN%

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng, allure

I have a problem with allure reports. When I run command ./gradlew allureReport after tests execution I've got an empty report with text like 'Allure Report unknown NaN%'. Does anyone have the same problem?
Here is my build.gradle configuration file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1"
}
}

plugins {
    id "io.qameta.allure" version "2.8.1"
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

allure {
    version = '2.8.1'
    autoconfigure = true;
    aspectjweaver = true;
resultsDir = file('/build/allure-results')
reportDir = file('build/allure-results')
}

group 'com.poc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useTestNG()
    dependsOn cleanTest
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-firefox-driver', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-safari-driver', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-edge-driver', version: '2.47.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.13'
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.8.1'
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but PDFBox is at 2.0.17. 2.0.1 was from around 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the allure-maven dependency under your dependencies section.I think that's why you are getting this NaN% error.

Comment: I am using allure with pytest. I am also getting the same error. Can you help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are spaces in one of the parent folder names. So, if there are spaces in folder name, keep the folder name in double quotes. Refer to the example below:

Run Allure command(allure serve) by keeping folder name in double quotes.
Suppose folder name is **test automation**

Incorrect: `allure serve D:\test automation\webautomation\allure-results`

Correct: `allure serve D:\"test automation"\webautomation\allure-results`

Comment: How to do this on mac?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and you have to specify the path within the double quotes in the command prompt if there are any white spaces between the folder names.

For example, if your allure results are in the following folder - D:\test automation\webautomation\allure-results, you have to specify the command as below.

```
allure serve "D:\test automation\webautomation\allure-results"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the correct report folder location
Paste below report generation command in Terminal:
allure serve "D:\pythonProject\pythonProject\SeleniumPython\SeleniumFramework\tests\SeleniumFramework\reports\allureReports"

NOTE: Before copying the report location path first check report is there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).